# Some help with an RSS feed

Tags: php, html, xml, validation, rss

I need some help with an RSS feed I'm working on. This is the code of an item:

```
        <item>
            <title>Team Fortress 2</title>
            <link>http://wormgineers.com/index.php?page=File&id=228</link>
            <description><[CDATA[Map with characters from Team Fortress 2.]]></description>
            <guid>228</guid>
        </item>
```

(Also, I'm not sure if I'm doing the CDATA thing right.)

Apparantly, the feed fails because this is wrong:

[image: Validation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `&` is starting an entity and you're not closing it with an `;`. Try the good old `&amp;` if you want a literal `&`.

Also, you are doing "CDATA" wrong.

```
<![CDATA[Text]]>
```

is the correct syntax.